# How do I pass an Eigen matrix row reference, to be treated as a vector?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a function that operates on a Vector reference, e.g.

```
void auto_bias(const Eigen::VectorXf& v, Eigen:Ref<Eigen::VectorXf>> out)
{
  out = ...
}
```

and at some point I need to have this function operate on a Matrix row. Now, because the default memory layout is column-major, I can't just Map<> the data the row points to into a vector. So, how do I go about passing the row into the above function so that I can operate on it?

The not-so-pretty solution is to have a temp vector, e.g.

```
VectorXf tmpVec = matrix.row(5);
auto_bias(otherVector, tmpVec);
matrix.row(5) = tmpVec;
```

but is there a way of doing it directly?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you be clearer about the problem?

Comment: If you're always accessing this particular matrix rowwise, then it might pay for you to declare it with row-major storage instead. Then you could apply the trick you referred to.

Comment: Jason, nah, sadly I don't have that option. Overall my data is column-major oriented, but in a few obscure cases I have to operate on it row-wise.


Lightness, what part is unclear? Jason seems to have understood it.

Answer (score 3):

You can allow `Ref<>` to have a non default inner-stride (also called increment), as follows:

```
Ref<VectorXf, 0, InnerStride<>>
```

See the example function `foo3` of the Ref's [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html).

The downside is a possible loss of performance even when you are passing a true `VectorXf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your function to take a reference to the row type (which is a vector expression) instead of a vector. This is really only manageable with a template to infer that type for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

template<typename V>
void set_row(V&& v) {
   v = Eigen::Vector3f(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f);
}

int main() {
   Eigen::Matrix3f m = Eigen::Matrix3f::Identity();
   set_row(m.row(1));

   std::cout << m;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I particularly like this answer,  as it has the lowest required internal understanding of Eigen. If somebody later picks up my code, they can treat the function as just receiving a vector.