# How pass Eigen matrix row reference (to be treated as a vector) to a func implemented in another .cpp?

Tags: c++, eigen

Hope you can help me.
My question derives from another question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144223/how-do-i-pass-an-eigen-matrix-row-reference-to-be-treated-as-a-vector)

Inside that page **rhashimoto** gives a good answer to a similar question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

template<typename V>
void set_row(V&& v) {
   v = Eigen::Vector3f(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f);
}

int main() {
   Eigen::Matrix3f m = Eigen::Matrix3f::Identity();
   set_row(m.row(1));

   std::cout << m;
   return 0;
}
```

**The problem is when you need to put the set_row function into another cpp file**. **In this way, you get the undefined reference error by the compiler.**
I found a way to solve [here](https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/c/c-undefined-reference-to-templated-class-function)

Where they say that you can solve:

1. moving the set_row function into the header file. OK! I tried and it works but I don't like it! Or
2. instantiating the template explicitly in the cpp file of the set_row function. This is what I would do. I tried without success.

Could you kindly show me how to achieve the last point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best done with templates in a header.

If you must put this in a CPP file, you can use a template function and explicit instantiation, as you suggested.  The key is to use the [Eigen `Block` type](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html).

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <int N, int M>
void set_row(Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, N, M>, 1, M> row) {
  // Note: this implementation is not correct in the general case.
  row = Eigen::Vector3f(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f);
}

// Explicit instantiation for fixed 3-by-3 case.
template void set_row(Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3>, 1, 3> row);

// Explicit instantiation for dynamic N by M case.
// Note that current implementation will not work.
template void set_row(Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> row);
```

Working Godbolt example:  https://godbolt.org/z/T4EYsc

Comment: Thank you very much. You got it, but I tried to solve the general case (dynamic matrix) using you answer whitout success could you kindly post an upgrade? In any case, many thanks.

Comment: What does "without success" mean?  Did it fail to compile, or fail at runtime?